# How to get template list from docusing account?

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

How to retrieve all template from Docusign api using vb.net.I manage to create multiple template through docusing website, and need to retrieve list of template from account.

Regards,
Aravind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add the nuget package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/ but this code is not for latest version.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Api
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Client
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Model
Imports Microsoft.AspNetCore.MvcPrivate Sub SurroundingSub()

    Dim config = New Configuration(New ApiClient(basePath))
    config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
    Dim templatesApi As TemplatesApi = New TemplatesApi(config)
    Dim options As TemplatesApi.ListTemplatesOptions = New TemplatesApi.ListTemplatesOptions()
    options.searchText = "Example Signer and CC template"
    Dim results As EnvelopeTemplateResults = templatesApi.ListTemplates(accountId, options)
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, where i get accessToken ? is it IntegratorKey ? and which version of docusign api version will work ? i installed docusign api 4.3 version

Comment: 4.3 is version of the SDK, not the API, and it should work with code above

Comment: as for how to get access token, you will need to read about authentication and how to use it. The information can be found here - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/setup-authentication/

Comment: Happy to help. Please feel free to ask additional questions as needed.